# How to store E-Mail in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

How to store E-Mail in MongoDB using python, like From, To , Date, Body, Nested Replies.. I have tried to implement it using imaplib, but not able to implement it, Can anyone please assist?

Do we have any other option to store this information in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

> `imaplib` implements a client for communicating with Internet Message
>   Access Protocol (IMAP) version 4 servers.

To save it in a database you need to create a Document with certain keys in it.

**Example document structure:**

```
json_data = '{"from_email" : "<some email>", "to_email" : "<some email"' .....}'
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, I did use imap to setup the connection with server and read mails, but I am stuck at parsing mails , how to get From,To, Body Text from plain text?

Comment: The email must have some format.... Check the type of email received. If it is returning email then there must be something which will help you parse the data too.. Thank you!